Sending email from external SMTP server to internal addresses
We have an externally hosted server that needs to be able to send email to both external and our internal email addresses.
This server is using the SMTP service provided by the hosting company and is able to send email to external addresses with no problems (from server[AT]mydomain.com to customer[AT]gmail.com). SPF and DKIM are set up for this server.
But if we try to send email to our internal addresses (hosted on Exchange Online) the email is never received (from server[AT]mydomain.com to user[AT]mydomain.com).
The server(AT)mydomain.com address can receive email on Exchange from internal and external addresses with no problems, but we are not seeing any bounce messages.
We do not see these failed email in message trace or quarantine.
Any ideas on what settings I might be missing or where I should look next?

We gave up on getting this working using the external SMTP server for sending directly. We ended up setting up a SMTP Relay using Exchange Online.
The SMTP Relay allows unauthenticated access to send email as our domain from the specific IP address of the external server.
This is less secure than we wanted, but because it is a dedicated public IP on the server we are okay with it.

Here are a few areas to check and some potential solutions:

Ensure that your SMTP relay is correctly configured to send emails
to your internal Exchange Online addresses. You might need to set up
an Inbound Connector in Exchange Online to allow emails from your
external server.

Verify that the SMTP AUTH is enabled for the mailbox being used to
send emails. This can be done through the Exchange Online admin
center.

Check if you have a connector set up in Exchange Online to accept
emails from your external server. The connector should be configured
to accept emails from the IP address of your external server.

While you mentioned that SPF and DKIM are set up, ensure that the
SPF record includes the IP address of your external server. This
helps Exchange Online to recognize the emails as legitimate.

Since you mentioned that the emails are not appearing in message
trace or quarantine, it might be worth checking the Exchange Online
Protection (EOP) settings to ensure that the emails are not being
silently dropped due to any filtering rules.

Double-check the SMTP settings on your external server. Ensure that
it is using the correct SMTP server name (), port (587 or 25), and
that TLS/StartTLS is enabled.



Thank you for the suggestions.



no SMTP Relay, as the external server is sending directly, not relaying through Exchange.


I thought this should not be needed as the account on the external server is sending the email?


We have an inbound connector set up using the IP address of the external server.




We verified the SPF record, and checked the headers of test emails that SPF passed.
I will check the EOP settings, although I thought that EOP filtered messages would still show up in a trace.
Since the SMTP server can send to external addresses, I am guessing the settings are correct.  Currently using port 587, but we are about to test with port 465 as well.


Here are some further suggestions:

Make sure your inbound connector is configured correctly, specifically verify that the connector allows mail from the external server's IP address.
Since you mentioned that you're testing port 465, I recommend that you go ahead and test that. Different ports may give different results, especially with firewall or network configurations.



While messages you think are filtered by EOP will still show up in your traces, sometimes a specific rule or policy may cause mail to be silently dropped. Double-check all of your EOP settings to make sure there aren't any rules that would block these messages.
Enable detailed SMTP logging on your external server. This will help you see detailed information about the mail delivery process, which may reveal the source of the problem.

